# Folder missing while logged in as root user to ec2 instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, root

I connected to ec2 instance using filezilla and uploaded a folder. When I login from putty to access the folder, i see the folder in .ssh directory. However, when login as a root user (sudo -i), I don't see the folder in .ssh directory. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Are you using the same user in both cases? When you use sudo, you also don't automatically get changed to that users home directory.

Comment: I am not sure...how do I make sure I am using same user?